# How to retrieve value from jQuery UI Dialog loaded from external page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

As following, suppose I have a click button in A.html to open a ui dialog, 
and the dialog will load the B.html as content.

So, if I want to get the value which id=inputName in B.html after the user click the button "ok" on the dialog, how can I do? I always get "undefined".

Sorry that maybe a stupid problem becase I'm new to jQuery.
I will very apreciate if you can help me.

A.html

---

```
$(function(){
    $('#name').click(function(){
        var aaa = window.parent.$.dialog({
            buttons: {
                'ok': function(){
                    //get the value from B.html(ex.the value which id=inputName)
                    $aaa.dialog('close');
                }
            }
        });

        var link = 'B.html';
        aaa.load(link);
        aaa.dialog('open')
    });
}); //jquery code


<div>
    <input type="button" value="input your name" id='name'>
</div>  //html code
```

---

B.html

---

```
<input type="text" name="inputName" id="inputName"/>
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I would like to get the value in B.html for the purpose of CGI by ajax request.
In another way, I done this work adding following code to   **B.html**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var okBtn = $('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').children("button:last");
okBtn.click(function(){ ajaxRequest(); });

function ajaxRequest() {
        var data
        data.name = $('#inputName').val();
        var url="(cgi link)";
        $.get(url,data);
        return;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that .load() is asynchronous.

A possible solution is below. The point is that you can pop up a dialog only upon load completion, i.e., in a callback. Please note that in the example below, an invisible element is created as a holder for your loaded HTML.  When load is complete, you can traverse its children or just get your element from the document:

```
<h1 id="dialogtest">Click me for a dialog!</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myElementValue = null;
$(function(){
    $('#dialogtest').click(function(){
    var dialogElement = document.createElement("div");
    var link = 'B.html';
    $(dialogElement).load(
        link,
        function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
            alert('Load complete: ' + responseText + "; " + textStatus + ";\n " + dialogElement.outerHTML);
            var myDialog = $(dialogElement).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                buttons: {
                    'ok': function(){
                        // You can traverse the childNodes of dialogElement, or do just thie following.
                        // For example, this is the value of a text node:
                        myElementValue = document.getElementById("myElement").childNodes[0].data;
                        alert(myElementValue);
                        myDialog.dialog('close');
                    }
                }
            });
            $(myDialog).dialog('open'); // Can autoOpen it above instead
        }
    );
    });
}); //jquery code
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems like it doesn't work for me,and I have found the another possible solution in this work.

Comment: It does work as is but, true, it couldn't be just copied and pasted into your code.

Comment: Yes,I know, but in this work I need to use 'window.parent.$.dialog' to popup the dialog which has customized.
Maybe something wrong in the substitution.